# VirtualAlloc передает не выделяет память из оперативной памяти?

Tags: c++, winapi

*VirtualAlloc* с флагом *MEM_COMMIT* выделяет ранее зарезервированному региону память из файла подкачке на жестком диске. Так пишет Рихтер и другие авторы статей. Происходит ли выделение оперативной памяти функцией *VirtualAlloc*, если есть свободные участки оперативной памяти?

Где найти информацию?

Comment: MSDN говорит о том, что память будет выделена либо из памяти, либо с диска. Так что, думаю, надо смотреть Русиновича.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос не имеет смысла. Важно лишь то, что до вызова `VirtualAlloc` с флагом `MEM_COMMIT` некоторый диапазон виртуальной памяти не был доступен процессу - а после вызова стал доступен.

Выделяется память сразу или при первом обращении, в файле подкачки, в оперативной памяти - или сразу в обоих местах - все это не важно, потому что в любом случае ей можно пользоваться.

Comment: @user193309 Добавлю к этому лишь что разница между оперативной памятью и файлом подкачки абстрагирована от вас подсистемой виртуальной памяти.